# Mounting error with Quota : mount: / not mounted already, or bad option

Tags: debian, quota

So I try to activate quota options in /etc/fstab by adding ",usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0" :

before :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda2       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime      0       1
/dev/sda3       /home   ext4    defaults,relatime       1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
```

after :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda2       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0      0       1
/dev/sda3       /home   ext4    defaults,relatime       1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
```

But after the modification, I get the following message :

```
mount -o remount /

mount: / not mounted already, or bad option
```

Any idea ? This is driving me mad.

EDIT :

Also, I have the following message :

```
quotacheck -avugm
quotacheck: Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: Aucun fichier ou dossier de                                              ce type
quotacheck: Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: Aucun fichier ou dossier de                                              ce type
quotacheck: Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: Aucun fichier ou dossier de                                              ce type
quotacheck: Cannot stat() mounted device /dev/root: Aucun fichier ou dossier de                                              ce type
quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota                                              option.
```

Comment: What is the output of "mount", without arguments?

Comment: Add the fs_type e.g. `mount DEVICE -t ext4 MOUNT_POINT. Note that forgetting the FS_TYPE would give me the same error than you on Debian Wheezy at least.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error. Using the complete command form, the one with `<device>` and `<mount-point>` arguments, worked for me. In your specific case, the command would be:

```
# mount -o remount /dev/sda2 /
```

Answer (score 0):

`quotaoff -a` might help.

Sorry I don't have the time right now to read all the rules of answering and the formatting, just wanted to help.